# Unable To Edit Web Query In Excel

Tags: .net, wcf-data-services, excel-2003

Have a WFC Data Service with an ADO.NET Entity Data.  Also tested with Netflix ODATA.  Can view and query in the browser.  In Excel I can query a Web Service via Import Data.   But I cannot edit the query in Excel.  Edit is grayed out.   I have to clear the data and start fresh.  How can I get Excel to let me edit the web query.   Thanks

Comment: We meet again. :) I'm working from a more recent version of Excel, so we'll start with the comments. Can you try this: From the **Data** tab, click on **Connections** > double-click your connection > **Definition**. Can you edit the connection string there?

Comment: @MarkStafford-MSFT On 2003 Data is a menu item and not finding Connection(s) anywhere.   I can remote to a box with Excel 2010 and there I can edit the ODATA query via Data, Connection.  On Excel 2003 if it query directly to SQL then the Edit menu command is hot.  But on 2003 with a Web Query executed the Edit menu command is grayed out.  If  that is just how it is then OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel versions 2010 and later include an OData ADO.NET provider that is actually intended to connect to OData sources. In Excel 2010, you'll need to get [PowerPivot](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/powerpivot.aspx) to have full OData support, and that support will be for v2 feeds. Somewhere down the road we will release an update for that provider that has v3 support.

When you are using PowerPivot you should be able to modify the URL for accessing the OData feed.